unable to create kubernetes cluster
INFO heat.engine.resource [req-a07c57cb-9a2c-4709-b5e0-7674ffabc2eb admin admin - default default] CREATE: TemplateResource "0" [984dd47a-6f51-4395-ace8-7d3db5b8da23] Stack "kubernetes-cluster555-sycnws7np22h-kube_masters-fzhufvl6zbu3" [cdb8a3cf-458a-44ac-b564-4a84dc1e464c]
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/engine/resource.py", line 916, in _action_recorder
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource     yield
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/engine/resource.py", line 1028, in _do_action
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource     yield from self.action_handler_task(action, args=handler_args)
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/engine/resource.py", line 978, in action_handler_task
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource     done = check(handler_data)
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/engine/resources/stack_resource.py", line 408, in check_create_complete
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource     return self._check_status_complete(self.CREATE)
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/heat/engine/resources/stack_resource.py", line 461, in _check_status_complete
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource     raise exception.ResourceFailure(status_reason, self,
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource heat.common.exception.ResourceFailure: resources[0]: Stack CREATE cancelled
2024-04-22 07:59:42.995 389399 ERROR heat.engine.resource
2024-04-22 07:59:43.005 389399 INFO heat.engine.stack [req-a07c57cb-9a2
resourses are available
